# How to get a folder location from the bin folder inside a dll project?

Tags: c#, dll

I'm creating a dll project. For one type of communication the dll needs to send Emails based on .txt templates.

example of the folder location :

```
C:\VisualStudioProjects\GeneratorApp\Bin\Debug (Or release) \Documents
```

for calling the Folder where these .txt files reside I used ( in the project of the dll)

```
var folderName = "Documents";
Path.Combine(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location + folderName);
```

In the first place it worked, but when calling the function from the dll via a webservice this address no longer is correct resulting in **FileNotFoundExceptions**.

the documents folder and all its .txt files are being copied to the the output bin. (Copy always).

I also tried the following methods which of course gave other results but couldn't help me.

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

or

```
var dm = typeof(AppDomainManager);
dm.Assembly.Location;
```

Any thoughts of how i can solve this problem?

EDIT:

Various output that i received:

```
GetEntryAssembly = null => no location to grab
GetExecutingAssembly Location = "C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\Temporary ASP.NET Files\\#####\\d37e9080\\ff60155b\\assembly\\dl3\\24596b30\\c542f015_588ccf01\\GeneratorApp.dll"
AppDomainManager Location = "C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\mscorlib.dll"
```

Comment: Have you tried to dump or debug to see the address at which it tries to find the templates? What is returned by Path.Combine(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location + folderName) in working environment?

Comment: @EugenePodskal: See Edited post for the outputs

Comment: It looks like ASP.NET hosting makes very good work in obfuscating everyting. Have you checked the contents of these dirs?

Comment: I really suggest you to create an entry in your web.config for these kind of paths. In this way you are free from the hassle to reconstruct your location from the location of your assemblies.

Comment: yes i did and besides the dll there is no folder which will hold the .txt files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) say that Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() will return the assembly which uses your dll, because it is the entry assembly and not your dll.

It worked in your test project because all your exe and dlls were in one location which can be otherwise for your working environment.

Try to use [Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

And are you sure that you have marked these files as `Resource` on the Properties tab?

Or you can try to embeb these templates as resources into your dll if they are a static data which won't be changed often

Comment: I'm going to try to add them as being resources, i'll get back to you with the results